# Переопределение стилей CSS

Tags: gwt, javascript, java, css

У меня есть стандартный контрол. Я наследуюсь от него. У одного элемента, этого контрола, выставлено свойство

```
white-space:pre
```

Как его убрать или выставить размер white-space'а, равный нулю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если этот стандартный контрол не содержит элементов, до вашего добавления, вы можете сделать так.

```
Element element = control.getElement();
element.setInnerHTML("");
```

После этого можете добавлять свои элементы.

Answer (score 0):

Можно установить стандартную величину:

```
white-space: normal
```

Больше информации: http://htmlbook.ru/css/white-space

Comment: Нет, это не поможет. Остается полоска, примерно в 10 пикселей. Если смотреть в код разметки, можно увидеть надпись - "(whitespace)". Она и занимает эти 10 пикселей. Ее и нужно убрать.

Answer (score 0):

> white-space: normal !important

Таким образом это свойство установится и не будет перезаписано вовсе.